# Selected Index doesn't change

Tags: c#, html, select

I have an ASP.NET DropDownList control, with a onSelectedIndexChanged event. I also have the AutoPostBack="true" that many have said would fix the problem. However I don't think that is where the problem lays... My Html code and C# code are below for reference. The thing is the code works, but only when I press the enter key while editing the drop down box. If I simply click on an object in the drop down then the event will not fire. If I change the selected item so the "selected" text in the drop down says "ASP" and I then inspect the element using the browser I see that the Selected="True" part of the ListItem is still on the first item... It doesn't change in there. It changes with an enter key but not with a mouse click. Any help is welcome and much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <asp:DropDownList id="Select1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Select1_SomethingChange" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Select one...">Select one...</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ActionScript">ActionScript</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="AppleScript">AppleScript</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Asp">Asp</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="BASIC">BASIC</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void Select1_SomethingChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //something is meant to happen here
}
```

Comment: Change autopostback="true" to AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: I was typing it out in the question, its right in the code... I didn't copy from the code

Comment: I edited the question, it should be right now... sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by data binding your dropdownlist in Page_Load method.
Please, surround it (data binding) with

```
if(!IsPostBack){
// data binding.
}
```

Hope, it help!

Comment: @Egor..Yes..this is the only thing that might be missing..Kaster worth trying it!

Comment: I am not binding any data from anywhere, the page_Load method is as empty as can be... The code I posted is the code that is there, there is nothing else to it. I did think about that too, that the list may not even be there when you click but I checked that and that is not the cause, if it was then the enter key wouldn't work either

Comment: In this way I can suggest to copy DropDownList to the new asp.net page and test it there. The code from your post works for me, so I think something not related to DropDownList control may cause this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

maybe you miss this option...

Comment: Just find out, thanks to your answer, that `asp:DropDownList` doesn't fire SelectIndexChanged because it doesn't post back on change by default. Your answer solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, there could be something in code which changes the implementation. I have debug your code and it's showing the selected item in output window. Please verify if there is some javascript code which is causing issue to call dropdown selectedIndexChanged event.

```
  protected void Select1_SomethingChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        Debug.WriteLine(ddl.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
```